# Handle CXF Exception

Tags: exception, service, web, cxf

I use @WebFault annotation to handle my CXF exception on my web service, it's work fine for parsing exception but I can't catch all of these !

I explain it, if an exception like this show up :

> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.

I'm not able to catch it in my web service's methods.

The main goal is to handle broken communication with the client.

If anyone have an idea, realy appreciate :)